# ArcGIS Pro pixellates vector marker symbol when published as web feature layer

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, vector, arcgis-online

I've added multiple SVG images to a feature layer as custom symbols in ArcGIS Pro. While these show up exactly as expected in ArcGIS Pro, the same symbols appear pixellated once the feature layer is published to ArcGIS Online.

[image: Correct rendering of vector symbols in ArcGIS Pro]

[image: Pixellated rendering in hosted feature layer on ArcGIS Online]

I am inexperienced in both designing SVG images and creating custom symbols in ArcGIS so I do not understand whether there is a problem with the ArcGIS settings or the way I have created the SVG file.

Is it possible to publish custom vector symbols within feature layers to ArcGIS Online?

---

I managed to get some slightly better results by adding the custom vector symbol as a new style in ArcGIS Pro - that is, ArcGIS Pro seems to display the symbol in its own menus in a way that looks more like one of the default symbols. However, whenever the feature layer is published online the symbol is still pixellated. Seems like a low-quality conversion from vector to raster during the upload process.